# How to pass variable in Ajax, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use PHP for almost one year, but I encounter a problem that confuse me for few days. As we know that we can use Ajax to pass variable to PHP then get response back for display. But how can I get the variable from one block of code to anther? Well Let me describe my problem in the code. Because my code has a very large size, so I just put a simplify version here.

```
<?php
  $array = [1,2,3,4,5];
//first Ajax call
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $value= $_POST['value'];
    $array[$id] = value; //The first call is mainly to update the value of $array
    echo $value;
    exit();
}

//Second Ajax call
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
     print_r($array);   //I want to use $array here, but I got the original 
     .....              //one.So what should I do to get the updated $array 
                        //from last Ajax call? 
}
```

If anyone could tell me how to solve it or maybe there is another way to get it, I will be very appreciate.

Comment: You need some permanent storage, for example a database, or if you just want it temporarily use `$_SESSION[]` to save data across a session (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AJAX calls to the page each initialise a new set of variables. You can't access $arrray from consecutive calls, but you could access a session variable.

Add `session_start();` at the top of the page, then

```
<?php
//first Ajax call
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
     $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
     $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['value'];         //The first call is mainly to update the value of $array
     echo $_SESSION['value'];
     exit();
}

//Second Ajax call
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    echo $_SESSION['id'],"<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['value'],"<br>";
}
```

**Note:** this snippet is making assumptions about the order of execution that might not be justified. For production code you should test the presence of `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` variables before you use them.

Comment: You forgot a bunch of ending semi-colons there Mike ;-)

Comment: Oh bother - I washed my hands today, and I can't do a thing with them :(

Comment: hehe no problemo. Time to switch from Palmolive to Sunlight ;-)

Comment: Yes. That's it, it is similar to the code of shopping cart. Thanks very much man. :)